# Power Query Transpose Combined Multi files

Tags: excel, powerquery, data-analysis, transpose

i would like to ask your advise for my current obstacle.
so i have multiple files with the same format need to be transposed and combine into single files.

the approach that i took is combine them into single file using **power query** and plan to transpose it, but it doesn't seem as an solution. below is the example

this is my current data :

[image]

and here with my desired output :

[image]

your advise would be greatly appreciated. thank you

ps : currently im able to transpose the data if its only one file. the issue is when i need to transpose with **multiple files combined** into one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each file, you want to do some processing like this

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
Keep = Table.FirstN(Source,3),
#"Removed Top Rows" = Table.Skip(Source,3),
#"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Removed Top Rows", [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
#"Add Column1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Promoted Headers",Keep{0}[Column1], each Keep{0}[Column2]),
#"Add Column2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Add Column1",Keep{1}[Column1], each Keep{1}[Column2]),
#"Add Column3" = Table.AddColumn(#"Add Column2",Keep{2}[Column1], each Date.From(Keep{2}[Column2]),type date)
in #"Add Column3"
```

[image]

then you can simply combine all them together

so some sample code to transform and combine all XLSX files in a directory would be

```
let Process = (xTable as table) as table => let
    zTable = Table.DemoteHeaders(xTable),   
    Keep = Table.FirstN(zTable,3),
    #"Removed Top Rows" = Table.Skip(zTable,3),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Removed Top Rows", [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Add Column1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Promoted Headers",Keep{0}[Column1], each Keep{0}[Column2]),
    #"Add Column2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Add Column1",Keep{1}[Column1], each Keep{1}[Column2]),
    #"Add Column3" = Table.AddColumn(#"Add Column2",Keep{2}[Column1], each Date.From(Keep{2}[Column2]),type date)
in #"Add Column3",  

Source = Folder.Files("C:\temp2\"),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Extension] = ".xlsx")),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Filtered Rows", "GetFileData", each Excel.Workbook([Content],true)),
#"Expanded GetFileData" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added Custom", "GetFileData", {"Data", "Hidden", "Item", "Kind", "Name"}, {"Data", "Hidden", "Item", "Kind", "Sheet"}),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded GetFileData", "Data2", each Process([Data])),
List = List.Union(List.Transform(#"Added Custom1"[Data2], each Table.ColumnNames(_))),
#"Expanded Data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added Custom1", "Data2", List,List),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded Data",{"Content", "Extension", "Date accessed", "Date modified", "Date created", "Attributes", "Folder Path", "Data", "Hidden", "Item", "Kind"})
in  #"Removed Columns"
```